# Using Doppler velocimetry with digital signals such as Bluetooth

Tags: frequency, digital-communications

I have found several sources describing how to use Doppler velocimetry/anemometry to measure the Doppler shift with analog signals, but i cannot find much about using this method for digital signals such as Bluetooth.  I was wondering if it were possible to use Doppler velocimetry/anemometry with digital signals? If so i was wondering if I could use it with the Bluetooth capabilities(2400 MHz – 2483.5 MHz) of an iPhone?

Comment: There's nothing that would prevent you from doing the same analysis with digital signals, but you would need access to a sample of the modulated RF signal. On a cell phone, you're likely in the best case to just get a stream of demodulated bits out of the RF receiver, if not data decoded at a much higher level in the network stack.

Comment: Could the cell phone even detect a doppler shift if it were moving at a velocity say walking speed(3 mph) away from the bluetooth signal emitter? Or is bluetooth frequency, 2.4 GHz, too large for such a small velocity?

Comment: Nevermind it would be a 10.7 Hz difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is whether you could ever use the Bluetooth radio in an iPhone to perform doppler velocimetry, I'm going to go out on a limb here and say no.

Most mobile devices are incredibly  modular. This means that the BT/WiFi radio (they are often combined into a single chip these days) is designed to handle all of the RF signal processing necessary, and then hand over only the **digital data** received, but never the **analog signals**.  By the time the signal is turned into digital data, any effects of multipath, channel noise, doppler shift, and other analog phenomena has been removed.  It is highly unlikely that any mass-produced cell phone would have access to the analog signal being received by the individual radios.

Comment: I was told that I could not use doppler velocimetry with Bluetooth because according to bluetooth.com:
 
 Bluetooth technology operates in the unlicensed industrial, scientific and medical (ISM) band at 2.4 to 2.485 GHz, using a spread spectrum, frequency hopping, full-duplex signal at a nominal rate of 1600 hops/sec.

        … adaptive hopping among 79 frequencies at 1 MHz intervals gives a high degree of interference immunity and also allows for more efficient transmission within the spectrum.

Aside from not be able to use the iphone to do it. is this true?

Comment: All of that is true, but that is not *why* you can't do it on an iPhone.  Since the frequency hopping is deterministic, you could still get the information you need out of the raw data, *if the raw data was available to you*.

Comment: In fact, with regards to the frequency hopping, it probably has some analogies to pulse-doppler radar. Once you have the decoded, demodulated data, you *know* exactly what the transmitted signal should have looked like. If you view each frequency hop as a separate pulse, you can coherently combine the information from each of the short pulses to converge on a solution.

Comment: This may sound dumb, but how could I know how the transmitted signal should have looked like? Is the transmitted signal's "expected" frequency hopping sequence contained in one of the transmitted packets?

Comment: The bluetooth spec defines how the frequency hopping occurs, and it is not trivial. However, the receiving bluetooth device is *synchronized* with the transmitting bluetooth device at pairing time in such a way that it always *knows* what frequency the transmitter will hop to next.  Otherwise, how would it know where to listen for the next packet?

Comment: Oh i see. It is predetermined. What if they are not connected meaning that the peripheral device is just advertising the information and the central device is picking it up. Would the central device be able to determine the expected frequency hop and from there break it down into pulses and find a solution for the doppler shift?

Comment: Much more difficult if you are not paired.  In isolation, you could just watch the spectrum and see where the activity occurs.  However, in the presence of other wireless devices operating in this band, it might be hopeless.  If you *happened* to be "listening" at the time the pairing occured, you might be better off, but my understanding of the BT spec is too limited to say exactly what you could and could not achieve.

Comment: For anybody following this post in the future I have just discovered that frequency hopping only occurs after a connection has been established.  There is no frequency hopping while a peripheral is advertising.

Comment: That's right, there will be no hopping while the device is in "pairing mode."  However, if the device you want to "listen to" is already paired with another device, then it will already be hopping frequencies and you might not be able to "get a lock" on it. (Sorry for the vagueries and non-technical terms. One of the frustrating things about working with BT is that the Bluetooth Standard uses completely different language than the common BT terms we are used to.)